# yarn test gives an error when running guest-book example

Tags: visual-studio, nearprotocol

I tried to run a yarn test in my terminal and I got error Command failed with exit code 9. Here is the complete error I had when I run `yarn test`

```
rasha@DESKTOP-HS0FEE9:~/guest-book$ yarn test
yarn run v1.22.15
$ yarn build:contract:debug && asp && jest
$ asb --target debug
/home/rasha/.nvm/versions/node/v17.0.1/bin/node: bad option: --experimental-wasm-bigint
error Command failed with exit code 9.
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 2):

I tried @Rasha fix and couldn't solve the issue.. `yarn upgrade` fixed the issue for me.

I hope that works for y'all

Answer (score 1):

After researching the error. The problem was in the node version which is v17.0.1. I downgraded the version to v13.13.0 and it works finally.